# Connecting to a RDS on AWS from different routers

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, relational-database

newbie here,

I am trying to send data to a RDS on AWS. When I try and connect to the DB from my residence and a nearby junior college the program is able to read and write to the MySQL database. When I use the internet at my office or a nearby university I am unable to connect... any ideas? I tried changing the port numbers but it didn't seem to have any affect...

```
    public int verifyPassword(string employeeName, string password)
    {
        string connStr = "server=endpointonAWS ;user=username;database=DB;port=2001;password=pswrd";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Successful");


            string sql = "INSERT INTO DB.employeeVerification (employeeName, password ) VALUES ('" + employeeName + "','" + password + "')";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Data Transfer Successful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Check the security group attached to the RDS instance to see whether any IPs are whitelisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect from some locations and not others then the problem almost certainly is not in your code, it's somewhere in the network.

I can think of 3 primary candidates:

1. DNS lookup failure.  Check to see if you can resolve the hostname to a correct IP address at the places where it fails.
2. Outbound filtering the local firewall.  Some businesses and universities expressly block outbound connections on non-standard ports.  If it's not HTTP or HTTPS then you might have problems.
3. Inbound firewall on AWS.

Of the 3 DNS is the easiest to diagnose and outbound filtering is probably the hardest to overcome since you likely don't have any access to the firewall rules if you're not part of the network admin team.

You can test outbound firewall blocks by putting an HTTP web service on port 443 on your target machine and trying to connect to it.  If it works for HTTPS but not for other ports then you can reasonably assume that there's a firewall in the way.